# Running google automl‘s custom model locally using docker fails to find path /tmp/mounted_model/0001

Tags: docker, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I have been working on a ML model to classify some images. After saving the model I have exported it to my machine using gsutil and have set the environment for the container as specified in google‘s [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/containers-gcs-tutorial?hl=en_US). I am doubting there is something wrong with the following command:

```
sudo docker run --rm --name ${CONTAINER_NAME} -p ${PORT}:8501 -v ${YOUR_MODEL_PATH}:/tmp/mounted_model/0001 -t ${CPU_DOCKER_GCR_PATH}
```

I do not really understand what does the :**/tmp/mounted_model/0001** stands for. Is it something automatically created? I even tried creating a folder in that directory and putting a the .pb model inside but error keeps occuring.
Please let me know if there is any solution for this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was in how I exported `YOUR_MODEL_PATH`.
That environment must be the folder path that contains `saved_model.pb` file

So, you have to download the `saved_model.pb` file into your machine.

```
gsutil gs://your_model_path/tf_saved_model-object-detection_20211124040443-2021-11-25T13:34:28.736944Z/ local_model_path

export YOUR_MODEL_PATH=local_model_path
```

Remember: `local_model_path` is a directory that inside contains the `save_model.pb` file.

Then run the command that you run before:

```
sudo docker run --rm --name ${CONTAINER_NAME} -p ${PORT}:8501 -v ${YOUR_MODEL_PATH}:/tmp/mounted_model/0001 -t ${CPU_DOCKER_GCR_PATH}
```